# In Xcode, can I keep keyboard focus in code window when performing searches and selecting files?

Tags: xcode

After interacting with the Project Navigator, or Search Navigator (The "folder" and "magnifying glass" tabs in the vertical pane on the left), is there a way to send keyboard focus to the code window-pane without clicking in the pane? Clicking has the side-effect of de-selecting selected text and moving the cursor position which in some cases is undesirable. The usual tab-stop mechanism doesn't seem to include the code pane in Xcode.

This is most frustrating when clicking project-wide search-results (which opens the file and selects the matching text for you, but doesn't put keyboard focus there) or clicking on files to temporarily look at a different file. In the latter case I may wish to preserve my cursor position and any already selected text in each file.

Comment: In a .m or .h file, just press tab to move the cursor from search field to your code.  For .plist files, Xcode 5 fixes [this search issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690497/xcode-plist-automatically-jumps-to-the-top-after-a-search).

Comment: This relates the the project-navigator and search-navigator (not the in-file search within the code pane). Pressing tab from the project navigator edits the file-name, pressing tab from the search-navigator tabs between the search term and the result list (all on the left pane). Also, this is not to do with plists - it's to do with .h and .m files. Updated question to be more clear.